# Pass dependency to app.[Methods()] in program.cs in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

In .NET 5 and previous, we used to have a startup.cs file, with ConfigureServices and Configure Method inside. In below function I have added ILoggerManager as parameter of the function and then passed it to app.ConfigureExceptionHandler function.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerManager logger) 
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.ConfigureExceptionHandler(logger);
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

But with .NET 6 there is no startup.cs file and only program.cs file. There is no ConfigureService or Configure methods inside program.cs and all methods or functions are being called in a procedural way without any class or methods declaration like below:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var logger = new LoggerManager();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DocumentDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DocumentStore")));
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerManager, LoggerManager>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.ConfigureExceptionHandler(<how to pass dependency here>);

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

My question is how can I pass a dependency to app.ConfigureExceptionHandler() function in .NET 6. I could not find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are creating `LoggerManager` yourself (`var logger = new LoggerManager();`) you can simply do:

```cs
app.ConfigureExceptionHandler(logger);
```

If you prefer to use the DI you can utilize `IServiceProvider` exposed via [`WebApplication.Services`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.webapplication.services?view=aspnetcore-6.0) property:

```cs
var resolvedLoggerManager = app.Services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerManager>();
app.ConfigureExceptionHandler(resolvedLoggerManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying obtain dependencies prior to calling `builder.Build()` (e.g. for use in services set-up), you can use an intermediate WebApplicationBuilder to build an additional WebApplication instance as below (Note that you cannot call `builder.Build()` twice, hence the need for the intermediate builder).

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Use intermediate builder to obtain configuration etc

var intermediateBuilder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var intermediateApp = intermediateBuilder.Build();

// Add services to the container.

var webHostEnvironment = intermediateApp.Services.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{webHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false)
                    .Build();

...
```

Comment: Or you use `builder.Environment.EnvironmentName`.